# FullCalendar (Filemaker webviewer) has lost interactivity when rendered, I think it is to do with perform javascript in web viewer step

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, filemaker, fullcalendar-5

I have used the Frudens Calendar as a template here which uses fullcalendar. I have heavily modified the original file which works really well.

I have since tried to merge with an existing solution, so followed all the guidance about which order to do everything in. It all functions correctly except when the calendar is rendered it now loses the interactivity. It is for the resource timeline, the resources show correctly and show the events correctly but the navigations buttons at the top for day, month next previous etc now don't do anything. I can move an event, which updates the table but doesn't update the calendar interface until I leave the layout and go back to it. I have a refresh button on the calendar but like the other nav buttons it doesn't work.
This is the fullcalendar html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>calendar</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
       <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.3.2/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <linkhref="/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    
    

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@5.3.2/main.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.3.2/main.min.js"></script>
    

    <script>
      var calendar;
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");
        //plugins: ['interactionPlugin', 'timeGrid', 'dayGrid', 'resourceTimeline'],
        
          calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          
          
          
        
          // --------------------
          // FullCalendar Scheduler License
          // https://fullcalendar.io/license/premium
          // --------------------
          schedulerLicenseKey: "CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives",

          // --------------------
          // Overall Display
          // --------------------
          // plugins:[interactionPlugin],
          headerToolbar: {
            left: "refresh prev,next",
            center: "title",
            right:
              "resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth,resourceTimelineYear resourceTimeline160Day resourceTimeGridDay",
          },
          customButtons: {
            refresh: {
              text: "Refresh",
              click: function () {
                FileMaker.PerformScript("T01_render_calendar", "");
              },
            },
          },
          
          height: window.innerHeight - 20,
          aspectRatio: 1.8,
          expandRows: false,
          handleWindowResize: true,
          windowResizeDelay: 100,
          windowResize: function (arg) {
            calendar.setOption("height", window.innerHeight - 20);
          },

          // --------------------
          // Views
          // --------------------
          views: {
             resourceTimelineDay: {
              buttonText: "D",
              slotDuration: "00:30:00",
              slotMinTime: "00:00",
              slotMaxTime: "24:00",
              // titleFormat: { day:'2-digit, month: 'short'},
              slotLabelFormat: [
                   { weekday: 'long' },
                     {hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', omitZeroMinute: true, meridiem: 'short'},
              //   // { hour: "2-digit", minute:"", meridiem },
              //   { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" },
                  
               ],
            },

             resourceTimelineWeek: {
              buttonText: "W",
              slotDuration: "03:00",
              slotMinTime: "00:00",
              slotMaxTime: "24:00",
              duration: { days: 7 },
              // titleFormat: { day:'2-digit, month: 'short'},
         
              weekText:"W",
              slotLabelFormat: [
                 { week: 'short'}, // top level of text
                   { weekday: 'short', day:'2-digit' },
                     {hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', omitZeroMinute: true, meridiem: 'short'},
              //   // { hour: "2-digit", minute:"", meridiem },
              //   { hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" },
                  
               ],
            },

            resourceTimelineMonth: {
              buttonText: "M",
            },
           
            resourceTimelineYear: {
              buttonText: "Y",
            },
            resourceTimeline160Day: {
              buttonText: "D(160)",
              slotDuration: "06:00",
              slotMinTime: "00:00",
              slotMaxTime: "24:00",
              type: "resourceTimeline",
              duration: { days: 160 },
            },
            resourceTimeGridDay: {
              buttonText: "D",
              slotDuration: "00:30:00",
              slotMinTime: "00:00",
              slotMaxTime: "24:00",
            },
          },
          initialView: "resourceTimelineDay",

          // --------------------
          // Date & Time
          // --------------------
          slotMinTime: "00:00",
          slotMaxTime: "24:00",
          // scrollTime: "09:00",
          firstDay: 1,
          nowIndicator: true,
          // --- Date Nav Links ---
          navLinks: false, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          // navLinkDayClick: function (date, jsEvent) {
            // alert(date);
            // calendar.changeView("resourceTimelineDay", date);
            // FileMaker.PerformScript("datePicker_select", dateConvert(date));
          // },
          // navLinkWeekClick: function (weekStart, jsEvent) {
            // calendar.changeView("resourceTimelineWeek", weekStart);
            // FileMaker.PerformScript(
              // "datePicker_select",
              // dateConvert(weekStart)
            // );
          // },
          // --- Week Numbers ---
          weekNumbers: true,
          // --- Date Clicking & Selecting ---
          selectable: true,
          selectMirror: true,
          // dateClick: function (arg) {
          //   alert("click");
          //   alert(arg.dateStr);
          // },
          select: function (arg) {
            const argJson = JSON.stringify(arg);
            FileMaker.PerformScript("fullCalendar_select", argJson);
            calendar.unselect();
          },

          // --------------------
          // Events
          // --------------------
          // --- Event Clicking & Hovering ---
          editable: true,
          
          
          eventClick: function (arg) {
            const argJson = JSON.stringify(arg);
            FileMaker.PerformScript("fullCalendar_eventClick", argJson);
          },
          // --- Event Dragging & Resizing ---
          eventResourceEditable: true,
          eventDrop: function (arg) {
            const argJson = JSON.stringify(arg);
            FileMaker.PerformScript("fullCalendar_eventDrop", argJson);
          },
          eventResize: function (arg) {
            const argJson = JSON.stringify(arg);
            FileMaker.PerformScript("fullCalendar_eventResize", argJson);
          },
          // --- Event Popover ---
          dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

          // --------------------
          // Resources
          // --------------------
          resourceOrder: "title",
          resourceAreaWidth: "15%",

          // --------------------
          // International
          // --------------------
          locale: "en",
          timeZone: "Europe/London",
        });
        calendar.render();
      });

      function setResourcesEventSources(fmParams) {
        const obj = JSON.parse(fmParams);
        if (obj.option) {
          for (let key in obj.option) {
            calendar.setOption(key, obj.option[key]);
          }
        }
        calendar.setOption("resources", obj.resources);
        calendar.setOption("eventSources", obj.eventSources);
        calendar.gotoDate(obj.gotoDate);
        
      }
     

      function dateConvert(date) {
        const y = date.getFullYear();
        const m = date.getMonth() + 1;
        const d = date.getDate();
        return y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
      }
    </script>
    <style>
      
      html,
      
      body {
        overflow: hidden; /* don't do scrollbars */
        font-family: Avenir, Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        },
      
      
      
      
      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="calendar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
†
```

I think the issue is somewhere here in the render calendar script:
[Script snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvdqB.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not reproducible, from the information supplied - all the header buttons work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vb7orh04/ . Maybe it's related to when you've got some actual events and resources in there. Please provide sample data of each such that we've got a [mre] of the issue. It looks like for some reason you're populating the data via the setResourcesEventSources function, rather than setting the properties directly on the calendar (why?) but we can't see how you're calling that function, or with what data.

Comment: As per [ask], do not post pictures of any of your code. Always copy and paste. Thanks.

Comment: Even with some dummy event/resource data added, there's no obvious problem - https://jsfiddle.net/vb7orh04/1/. Are you getting any JS console errors when you are using your calendar, or anything like that?

Comment: @ADyson, I can't copy and past from the FM script. It is not in text format. Where do I find JS console errors, I am pretty new to JS but I am now familiar with jSON which is good.

Comment: Open your browser's Developer Tools and look at the Console tab in there. In most browsers, F12 will open the Developer tools, or there's probably a menu item you can click.

Comment: It's not in a browser, it is via a web viewer in FileMaker. 19. I don't think FileMaker has a native Javascript error capture yet.

Comment: Ok. That's a pain. I know zilch about filemaker, admittedly. Have you tried to reproduce the issue in a real browser first, then?

Comment: I haven't because that would be quite a lot of work, and because I have a file with it working already I was hoping someone could suggest something they I have may have missed when integrating a file with another. I am sure it is to do with the script call to perform a script in the web viewer. This is where it seems to fall down. I have watched every script step in both the working file and not working file and this is the only place where it doesn't do the same thing. But there is no apparent way of seeing why!

Comment: the passing of data via JSON works fine, the tables update both ways, from the webviewer and from the table. But the web viewer which displays the UI for the calendar just stops interacting after that script step mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird you say that the interface doesn't update after you move an event from one area to another. Isn't that the update?

Full Calendar allows for the drag drop, which is the update. The eventDrop method does updating of the underlying record, but the event should move.

I'm also interested in why your prev / nav buttons don't work. I see nothing that prevents that.

Maybe this is the culprit:

```
 calendar.setOption("resources", obj.resources);
 calendar.setOption("eventSources", obj.eventSources);
```

According to the FC [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options) of setOption, setting resources and eventSources is not available in this manner. It has to be done another way.

Here you have to use the [addEventSource](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEventSource) or [refretchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) methods. And those are a bit tricky when using FileMaker as the data source. They can be done, and the Claris Full Calendar Add-on employs a method. But it's a bit roundabout.

I can provide more detail if you wish.

One more thing: in your FM Script, why the Go to Field[] step at the end? I never use that when I'm working with web viewer stuff.

Comment: Hi @J Brown, the strange thing about this is that it works perfectly in its own file. I have replicated everything exactly the same, I have spent hours checking every script and custom function, even though I imported them. The go to field ensures that no field is selected for cleanliness I guess. 

In terms of the add event source and refetchevents, I have seen it done via a global data field, more than one in some cases for things like holidays etc.

Comment: cont... I have moved the scripts and css to a global variable now, as I thought it may be something to do with the CSS and scripts being called from a URL, but it is still doing the same thing. I have checked and double checked all the permissions and extended privilege sets. All good.

Answer (score 0):

J Brown, thank you so much for your help with this.
For anyone else, the issue was with converting the date format to ISO from FM.
Not sure why it worked in the original file, maybe because of where it was originally written was not in the UK. We changed a custom function that simply converted the format of the system date.

This was a useful resource: https://community.jsinfm.com/home

Comment: Glad you resolved it, but a more useful answer would include the code of this function you needed to change, and an explanation of where it fits into the calendar functionality